# ARC + NSLocalizedString + NSMenuItem#title == Memory Issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, crash, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using ARC and generic Cocoa and still hitting memory issues. With `NSZombiesEnabled`, the following line points to the crash:

```
[self.menu itemWithTag:MYMenuItemStatus].title = NSLocalizedString(@"DISCONNECTED", nil);
```

With the error:

```
*** -[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

`self.menu` is defined as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSMenu *menu;
```

`MYMenuItemStatus` is defined as follows:

```
typedef enum {
    MYMenuItemStatus = 0,
    // and so on...
} MYMenuItem;
```

This code executes in a `Reachability` reachability-changed callback, if that helps explain anything. I'm at a loss, though. What am I missing?

#### Update:

`self.menu` (and its items) are initialized from a nib file (the menu property is an outlet).

Comment: Can you provide more code where you init self.menu and items please?

Comment: If you run the code under Instruments with the Zombies template, what do you find?

Comment: @anatoliy_v Updated: they're just IB-instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

I can assure you that there is nothing wrong with the code you are showing.